# Dreamweaver android app development build error?

Tags: android, dreamweaver

I am trying a simply hello world android app with dreamweaver 5.5. But when i hit build and emulate i get the message

```
Dreamweaver is unable to open "apptest" in the emulator. Please consult the build log at
```

and build log main errors

```
[echo] Install file not specified.

 [echo] 

 [echo] 'ant install' now requires the build target to be specified as well.

 [echo] 

 [echo] 

BUILD FAILED

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1124: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1191: No message
```

Anyone know how i can fix this?
regards

edit 1: build seems to be succesfull but still won't shop up in the emulator. I just see the emulator but without the app. I don't get it why the buildlog.log says "failed to launch"

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6 seconds


<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2\adb.exe kill-server
____________________
</DW>

Waiting for Android emulator to bootERROR: failed to launch Android emulator
```

EDIT 2: Now DMW gives the message:

> The emulation of apptest has completed successfully. Your
>   applicationbinary is located at.... -debug.apk

But still not showing up in the emulator, buildlog.log

```
Installing app into Android emulator
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Users\mainuser\Desktop\COMFUL~1.APP
C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat install
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\Users\mainuser\Desktop\COMFUL~1.APP\build.xml



install:

     [echo] Install file not specified.

     [echo] 

     [echo] 'ant install' now requires the build target to be specified as well.

     [echo] 

     [echo] 

     [echo]     ant debug install

     [echo]     ant release install

     [echo]     ant instrument install

     [echo] This will build the given package and install it.

     [echo] 

     [echo] Alternatively, you can use

     [echo]     ant installd

     [echo]     ant installr

     [echo]     ant installi

     [echo]     ant installt

     [echo] to only install an existing package (this will not rebuild the package.)



BUILD FAILED

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1124: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1191: No message



Total time: 0 seconds

Running app in Android emulator
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\DWPHON~1\android\scripts\ANDROI~2.BAT com.mainuser.apptest C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
____________________
</DW>
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.mainuser.apptest/.DefaultActivity }



Error type 3



Error: Activity class {com.mainuser.apptest/com.mainuser.apptest.DefaultActivity} does not exist.




<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2\adb.exe kill-server
____________________
</DW>
```

Comment: This may help you to solve the build target problem (at the bottom of the tutorial) http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/11/01/building-phonegap-applications-with-dreamweaver/.

Comment: @207 YES! Finally i see what i have built. Really appreciate you shared that tutorial. Haven't found it during my googling. Maybe you can add it as an answer so i can give you some reps.
Still have some issues with the emulator as it only works if the emulator is already running. (So i have to hit "build and emulate" a couple of times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you to solve the build target problem (at the bottom of the tutorial) http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/11/01/building-phonegap-applications-with-dreamweaver/

Comment: btw i get this error now: 
the connection to the server was unsuccessful. file:///android_asset/www/index.html) Do you know how i could fix this?

Comment: fix with adding this super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); to DefaultActivity class

Comment: hmm, but now the emulator reacts like little hobbits on a strike !